How to resolve a new field error in an azure-devops work item task that was deleted but continues to appear as required to save the task
How to resolve a new field error in an azure-devops work item task that was deleted but continues to appear as required to save the task. Note that the save button is not enabled for selection even if the field that appears as an error has already been excluded from the new task field list
I tried to clean the cache.
I deleted de new field which was mentioned in the error description
I filled in all the required fields but the error continue the same.

Hi Guilherme Toledo, welcome to SO. Please check the steps in my answer and see if there is any difference with yours. If there is any difference, please let me know and share some screenshots or your detailed steps by Edit your post. Thanks!

I tested the issue in my organization and didn't meet the error.
My steps:

Create a Test field in the work item type Bug and set it as required. Steps for "Add a custom field to a work item type" is here.

Create a new Bug work item and it will show the error "Field 'test field' cannot be empty" when I didn't fill in the field.


Remove the field from the bug. Please note that don't choose "hide from layout". If it is hide, the field will still be required when creating the work item.


Reflash the page and create a new Bug work item and it will not show the error "Field 'test field' cannot be empty". The Save button is enabled.




Many thank in advance for your help. We solved the error  and your support was very important.

Hi @GuilhermeToledo, glad to know that you have solved the error! If you solved the error by some special way, you could share your own answer. This may benefit others who encounter this problem in the future.
